# HPQC C# Create Test Planning Test

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center

Working on a QC integration tool and having trouble creating a test in the Test Plan - unfortunately the API is written for VB6, and I'm working in C#.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
private void HPQC_Create_Test_Plan_Test(TDConnectionClass tdConnection, string ParentFolderPath, string TestName)
    {
        try
        {
            TreeManager treeM = (TreeManager)tdConnection.TreeManager;
            ISysTreeNode ParentFolder = (ISysTreeNode)treeM.get_NodeByPath(ParentFolderPath);
            TestFactory TestF = (TestFactory)tdConnection.TestFactory;

            Test TstTest = (Test)TestF.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
            TstTest.Name = TestName;
            TstTest.Type = "MANUAL";
            TstTest.Post();

            HPQC_Status_Test_Plan.Text = "Test " + TestName + " created.";

            tdConnection.Logout();
            tdConnection.Disconnect();
            tdConnection = null;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HPQC_Status_Test_Plan.Text = "Test Creation Failed.";
            Console.WriteLine("[Error] " + ex);

            tdConnection.Logout();
            tdConnection.Disconnect();
            tdConnection = null;

        }
    }
```

The code errors out on the Post with a simple "Failed to Post" and I'm at a loss as to why.

Here's the API example in VB6:

```
Public Sub AddTest(FolderName$, TestName$)
```

Create new test.
 This example assumes that the subject folder containing the
 new test is directly under the root "Subject" folder.

```
Dim objTest As Test
Dim folder As SubjectNode
Dim testF As TestFactory
Dim TreeMgr As TreeManager
Dim Path As String

Dim Trees As List
Dim RootName As String
Dim SubjRoot As SubjectNode

'tdc is the global TDConnection object.
Set TreeMgr = tdc.TreeManager

' Use TreeManager.TreeRoot to get the list of subject
' root nodes from the tree manager.
' There is only one item in this list.
Set Trees = TreeMgr.RootList(TDOLE_SUBJECT)

' Get the name of the subject tree root in your project.
RootName = Trees.Item(1)

Path = RootName & "\" & FolderName

On Error Resume Next
Set folder = TreeMgr.NodeByPath(Path)
On Error GoTo 0

If folder Is Nothing Then 'Create the folder
    ' Get the SubjectNode root node object from the
    ' tree manager by name.
    Set SubjRoot = TreeMgr.TreeRoot(RootName)
    Set folder = SubjRoot.AddNode(FolderName)
End If

Set testF = folder.TestFactory
Set objTest = testF.AddItem(Null)
objTest.name = TestName
objTest.Type = "SYSTEM-TEST"
objTest.Post

Dim VerCtl As VCS
Dim bIsLocked As Boolean
Dim strLockedBy As String

Set VerCtl = objTest.VCS

VerCtl.Refresh

bIsLocked = VerCtl.IsLocked
strLockedBy = VerCtl.LockedBy

' After POST, Test is checked in.
Debug.Print "Is locked: " & bIsLocked
'Is locked: False
Debug.Print "Is locked by: """ & strLockedBy & """"
'Is locked by: ""

VerCtl.CheckOut -1, "To change state", True

VerCtl.Refresh

bIsLocked = VerCtl.IsLocked
strLockedBy = VerCtl.LockedBy

Debug.Print "Is locked: " & bIsLocked
'Is locked: True
Debug.Print "Is locked by: """ & strLockedBy & """"
'Is locked by: "User1"

' Take an arbitrary field to change.
Debug.Print "Status: """ & objTest.Field("TS_STATUS") & """"
'Status: ""

objTest.Field("TS_STATUS") = "Ready"

objTest.Post

VerCtl.CheckIn "", "Changed status"

VerCtl.Refresh

bIsLocked = VerCtl.IsLocked
strLockedBy = VerCtl.LockedBy

Debug.Print "Is locked: " & bIsLocked
'Is locked: False
Debug.Print "Is locked by: """ & strLockedBy & """"
'Is locked by: ""
```

End Sub

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gave it the weekend to think it over, and realized that the code above didn't have a parent attribute to link to in the tree. Unfortunately TreeManager in C# does not have TreeRoot to work with for some reason.

Worked around that by grabbing the path manually for the prototype - the user has to key in parent path like "Root\Subject" into a textbox.

The key attribute was the "TS_Subject" which is the NodeID of the folder that you want to attach the test to.

The following code works for me:

```
private void HPQC_Create_Test_Plan_Test(TDConnectionClass tdConnection, string ParentFolderPath, string TestName)
    {
        try
        {
            TreeManager treeM = (TreeManager)tdConnection.TreeManager;
            ISysTreeNode ParentFolder = (ISysTreeNode)treeM.get_NodeByPath(ParentFolderPath);
            TestFactory TestF = (TestFactory)tdConnection.TestFactory;

            Test TstTest = (Test)TestF.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
            TstTest.Name = TestName;
            TstTest.Type = "MANUAL";
            TstTest["TS_SUBJECT"] = ParentFolder.NodeID;
            TstTest.Post();

            HPQC_Status_Test_Plan.Text = "Test " + TestName + " created.";

            tdConnection.Logout();
            tdConnection.Disconnect();
            tdConnection = null;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HPQC_Status_Test_Plan.Text = "Test Creation Failed.";
            Console.WriteLine("[Error] " + ex);

            tdConnection.Logout();
            tdConnection.Disconnect();
            tdConnection = null;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar but more suited to generating a folder structure also.
Our root folder in QC is "Subject" but you can simply change this in order to create the specific folder you want. Also instead of setting the ["TS_SUBJECT"] title this is not required as we are using the node at the leaf node to create the tests into the specified folder.

```
private TestFactory addSubjectTreeStructure(String subjectField)
    {
        String folderRootString = subjectField;
        folderRootString = folderRootString.Replace("\\", "/");
        String[] folders = folderRootString.Split('/');

        // Test Plan Tree Manager
        TreeManager treeMgr = tdc.TreeManager;
        SubjectNode subjectNode = treeMgr.get_NodeByPath("Subject");

        ISysTreeNode node = (ISysTreeNode)subjectNode;

        // Creating the folders in test plan.
        for (int i = 0; i < folders.Length; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                node = node.FindChildNode(folders[i]);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                node = node.AddNode(folders[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + ".\nChild not found. Adding new node: " + folders[i]);
            }
        }

        // Set the leaf folder and then returning the TestFactory from where all test cases will be generated from.
        SubjectNode folder = treeMgr.get_NodeById(node.NodeID);
        return folder.TestFactory;
    }
```

Then by using the returned test factory you can create the tests in this folder.